# scanf() overwrits next variable

Tags: c, scanf, buffer-overflow

I am trying to get input from a user.

```
void InfoPrint(){
    char FirstName[20];
    char LastName[20];
    int BirthYear;
    printf("Input your First Name: ");
    scanf("%19s", FirstName);
    printf("\nInput your Last Name: ");
    scanf("%19s", LastName);
    printf("\nInput your year of birth: ");
    scanf("%4d", &BirthYear);
    printf("\n%s %s %d\n", FirstName, LastName, BirthYear);
}
```

Why when I input more then 19 characters in `FirstName` or `LastName` it overwrites my next variable?

Comment: `int clear_rest_of_line(void) { int ch; while (((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n')) /*void*/; return (ch == EOF); }`

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"it overwrites my next variable"` -- I strongly doubt that this statement is accurate. Please provide a [mre] of the problem with exact input, expected output and actual output. Such an example should include all `#include` directives and a function `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the input buffer still contains characters that will be read by a next call of `scanf`.

So if you entered for example 30 characters and pressed the Enter key then the first 19 characters will be read by the first call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%19s", FirstName);
```

and the 11 remaining characters will be read by the second call of `scanf`.

```
scanf("%19s", LastName);
```

Or for example if you will enter a sequence of characters that contains a space character like `"Hello World!"` then the first call of `scanf` will read the word `"Hello"` and the second call of `scanf` will read the sequence `"World!"`.

Comment: So you mean I should clean the rest of the buffer manually?

Comment: @Gendozz You should clean the input buffer somehow or issue an error and ask the user to repeat the input.

Comment: ok, I got you! Spasibo!

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel excuse me, the answer is considered